# Linker errors with flex and g++?

Tags: linker-errors, lex, flex-lexer

I'm running into some linker errors with `flex` when I try compiling the resulting scanner with `g++`.  If I give `flex` the following (very simple) script:

```
%%
.  ECHO;
```

Then run `flex` as

```
flex++ scanner.l
```

And then try compiling the resulting code as

```
g++ lex.yy.cc -ll
```

I get the following errors:

```
/tmp/ccD5WdY3.o:(.rodata._ZTV11yyFlexLexer[vtable for yyFlexLexer]+0x28): undefined reference to `yyFlexLexer::yywrap()'
/usr/lib/libl.a(libmain.o): In function `main':
/build/buildd/flex-2.5.35/libmain.c:30: undefined reference to `yylex'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm not sure why this is.  Am I linking in the wrong library with `-ll`?  If so, what should I do to fix this?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the topic, but don't you need a parser as well, which provides the `yylex` function? Using bison++?

Comment: Did you mean to tag this w/ Adobe Flex?

Comment: @KerrekSB no, while flex is often used with bison, it by no means is necessary to do so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned, I think `-ll` is unnecessary.
Probably `libl` contains the code like the following:

```
int main() { return yylex(); }
```

However, the scanner code generated by `flex++` doesn't contain free-standing
function `yylex`.
So if the scanner is linked with the above `main`, it cannot find `yylex`.
When the scanner is generated by `flex++`, that scanner needs a dedicated `main`
instead of linking with `-ll`, and the simplest `main` will be like the following:

```
int main() {
  for ( yyFlexLexer l; l.yylex(); ) {}
}
```

As for the usage of C++ scanner,
[this part](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Cxx.html#Cxx)
of flex document will help.

That being said, as the document says:

> the present form of the scanning class
>   is *experimental* and may change
>   considerably between major releases

I cannot recommend using C++ scanner positively.